# remove the computrace by flashing the bios

Tags: firmware-analysis, bios, uefi

Is there a way to remove the computrace by flashing the bios or deleting/altering the contents of it? Someone gave me a laptop and I found out that it was not usable because it was equipped with absolute computrace persistence and was reported as stolen and was frozen. Is there a way to remove the computrace?

Comment: In case it is the same model as in your other post: The update files for the BIOS look like it uses a TPM so changing the BIOS could lead to problems during boot. However, the same files also list lots of patched CVEs. Depending on your version one of those CVEs is maybe useful ...

Comment: i disabled the TPM, sorry for duplicate post with the same issue